# Unable to resolve the Error "string index out of range"

Tags: python

```
import sys 
x=input("Enter the string")   `# getting the input#`
i=1 
ctr=0 


 print(len(x))                  #printing the length of the whole line
    while(i<=len(x)):        
         if(x[i]=='a'):             
            ctr=ctr+1                    
         i=int(i+1) 


 print(ctr)
```

Comment: Please add more information to your question as to what you are trying to achieve so others can help.

Comment: Python uses 0-based indexing, so you want `i=0` and `i<len(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is causing the issue: `while(i<=len(x))`

You should remove the `=`, because string bounds are [0, len(x)-1]